# c# list <string> unable to convert string to datetime and string to int

Tags: c#

```
public UserAccount(List<string> data)
{
    this.UserIDNumber = data[0]; //issue here
    this.name = data[1];
    this.Username = data[2];
    this.Password = data[3];
    this.Birthday = data[4]; //issue here
    this.Address = data[5];
    this.City = data[6];
}
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm unable to convert two data types. If I use `this.Birthday.Tostring()` and `this.UserIDNumber.ToString()`

I get the error: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a var, prop, or indexer.

Comment: what is the type of `UserIDNumber`? int? long? what is the type of `Birthday`? DateTime? Come on, read some docs about how to convert strings to correct types...... At least type your title to google and see the results.....

Comment: The thing you're looking for in .NET is called "`TryParse`".

Comment: You're trying to convert the *actual* variable of your class to a different type. You can't do that. You can't temporarily "morph" what is an integer into a string just for now to hold a string value. `data[int]` is always going to give you a string, because it's a List of strings. You have to cast **those** values to the appropriate types.

Comment: Expanding on my previous comment, the error message you're getting says "the **left hand side of an assignment**" which is saying the variables on the left of the `=` in your line of code shouldn't be calling a method, such as `ToString()`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly convert the string to the correct type.

```
public UserAccount(List<string> data)
{
    this.UserIDNumber = Convert.ToInt32(data[0]); 
    this.name = data[1];
    this.Username = data[2];
    this.Password = data[3];
    this.Birthday = DateTime.Parse(data[4]); 
    this.Address = data[5];
    this.City = data[6];
}
```

Or the safe way, that will not throw an **exception** if the convert fails. But have in mind that you then can get corrupt data iy you not handling the default values.

```
public UserAccount(List<string> data)
{
    int id;
    this.UserIDNumber = int.TryParse(data[0], out id) ? id : 0; 
    this.name = data[1];
    this.Username = data[2];
    this.Password = data[3];
    DateTime date;
    this.Birthday = DateTime.TryParse(data[4], out date) ? date : DateTime.MinValue; 
    this.Address = data[5];
    this.City = data[6];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 this.UserIDNumber = Convert.ToInt32(data[0]);
 this.Birthday = DateTime.Parse(data[4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing (for both this and the datetime)

```
this.ErrorMessage = string.Empty;

  int parseInt = 0;
  if (!int.TryParse(data[0], out parseInt))
  {
    this.ErrorMessage += "Error Parsing the account number! data was: " + data[0];
    this.AcctNumber = -1;
  }
  else
  {
    this.AcctNumber = parseInt;
  }
```